# Horizontal scroll using mouse wheel ( C# & WinAPI )

Tags: c#, winapi, imessagefilter

I am creating a logic to scrolling the control under mouse position without focus (outlook style) in my form. I am able to achieve this behavior using IMessageFilter. However I am facing difficulty to apply a Horizontal scroll, if "SHIFT" key is pressed.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;


public partial class UI : Form
{
    MouseWheelMessageFilter mouseFilter = null;
    public UI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mouseFilter = new MouseWheelMessageFilter();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(mouseFilter);
        this.FormClosed += (o, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(mouseFilter);
    }
}

public class MouseWheelMessageFilter : IMessageFilter
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pt);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);


    public const int MK_CONTROL = 0x0008;
    public const int MK_SHIFT = 0x0004;

    public const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    public const int WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E;


    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            var shiftKeyDown = (char)((Keys)m.WParam) == MK_SHIFT;

            //apply the scroll to the control at mouse location
            Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
            IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pos);

            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero && hWnd != m.HWnd && Control.FromHandle(hWnd) != null)
            {
                if (shiftKeyDown)
                    //TODO: Horizontal scroll - Not working WM_MOUSEHWHEEL (0x020E)
                    //SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                else
                    //Vertical Scroll - working
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, m.WParam, m.LParam);
                return true;
            }
        }           
        return false;
    }
}
```

What should I need to do in the //TODO section to get horizontal scroll working?

Comment: A *lot* of applications don't support WM_MOUSEHWHEEL.  In a project I worked on, we had to write code to find scrollbars and programmatically manipulate them (which has a host of its own issues).

Comment: Couple more notes:  It's better to use `PostMessage` when sending messages to windows you don't own rather than `SendMessage`.  If you *must* send messages (instead of posting), use `SendMessageTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a guess, I can't test this myself, but I notice you are only filtering for:

```
if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
```

Do you need to filter for WM_MOUSEHWHEEL separately:

```
if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEHWHEEL)
```

Then perhaps you don't have to test for the shift key?

edit: this is what I was thinking:

```
public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEHWHEEL)
    {
        //apply the scroll to the control at mouse location
        Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
        IntPtr hWnd = WindowFromPoint(pos);
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero && hWnd != m.HWnd && Control.FromHandle(hWnd) != null)
        {
            SendMessage(hWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sorry if this doesn't work, I am not able to compile this up to test it right now, it's just a guess that you won't get WM_MOUSEWHEEL if the user has SHIFT held down (get WM_MOUSEHWHEEL instead)

Comment: Since I don't have a mouse that support horizonal scroll, i am trying to convert "SHIFT + Mosuse Scroll" to horizontal scroll. btw, You will get WM_MOUSEWHEEL even if you have pressed "Shift" key.